# Two EntityManagerFactories, TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

The **Spring MVC** application uses **SpringDataJPA** and hibernate. The production mode leverages **MySQL** but for the **unit tests I have set up H2DB** to run, both with separate java configuration. The application also utilizes Spring Security but its configuration I omitted below.

The appliaction starts up with the unit tests but at the first test (testOIC() see in the below code) I got the `"TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress"`.

```
 testException = org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: no transaction is in progress; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress, mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@1c581a0 testClass = OpenPositionsServiceTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class our.dcollect.configuration.AppConfiguration, class our.dcollect.configuration.HibernateConfigurationTest}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.web.WebDelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]].
```

The unit test I run with Propagation.**REQUIRES_NEW**, so it should have a transaction context. I am afraid I messed up something in the appliaction context. The posts I found in connection with this topic did not help a lot.

The ApplicationContext contains the following beans:
Spring Bean Definition Names in ApplicationContext (applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()):

```
===================================================
Bean: appConfiguration
Bean: authenticationManagerBuilder
Bean: autowiredWebSecurityConfigurersIgnoreParents
Bean: beanNameHandlerMapping
Bean: dataSource
Bean: dataSourceTest
Bean: defaultServletHandlerMapping
Bean: delegatingApplicationListener
Bean: dtoConverter
Bean: emBeanDefinitionRegistrarPostProcessor
Bean: enableGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer
Bean: entityManagerFactory
Bean: entityManagerFactoryTest
Bean: fileUploadController
Bean: fileUploadService
Bean: getInternalResourceViewResolverJsp
Bean: handlerExceptionResolver
Bean: hibernateConfiguration
Bean: hibernateConfigurationTest
Bean: hibernateProperties
Bean: httpRequestHandlerAdapter
Bean: initializeAuthenticationProviderBeanManagerConfigurer
Bean: initializeUserDetailsBeanManagerConfigurer
Bean: jpaContext
Bean: jpaMappingContext
Bean: jpaVendorAdapter
Bean: jpaVendorAdapterTest
Bean: multipartResolver
Bean: mvcContentNegotiationManager
Bean: mvcConversionService
Bean: mvcPathMatcher
Bean: mvcResourceUrlProvider
Bean: mvcUriComponentsContributor
Bean: mvcUrlPathHelper
Bean: mvcValidator
Bean: mvcViewResolver
Bean: objectPostProcessor
Bean: openIn....Repository
Bean: openPositionsService
Bean: org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator
Bean: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor
Bean: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor
Bean: org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor
Bean: org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor
Bean: org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor
Bean: org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor
Bean: org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor
Bean: org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory
Bean: org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor
Bean: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension#0
Bean: org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport_Predictor
Bean: org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#0
Bean: org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#1
Bean: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration
Bean: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration
Bean: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration
Bean: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration
Bean: org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration
Bean: org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor
Bean: org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionalEventListenerFactory
Bean: org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration
Bean: privilegeEvaluator
Bean: push....Repository
Bean: requestDataValueProcessor
Bean: requestMappingHandlerAdapter
Bean: requestMappingHandlerMapping
Bean: resourceHandlerMapping
Bean: securityConfiguration
Bean: sessionFactory
Bean: sessionFactoryTest
Bean: simpleControllerHandlerAdapter
Bean: springSecurityFilterChain
Bean: transactionAttributeSource
Bean: transactionInterceptor
Bean: transactionManager
Bean: transactionManagerTest
Bean: viewControllerHandlerMapping
Bean: webSecurityExpressionHandler
===================================================
```

Could you help? The relevant code parts I posted below.

**MVC configuration:**

```
package our.dcollect.configuration;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;


@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "our.dcollect")
public class AppConfiguration {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(AppConfiguration.class);

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolverJsp(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        viewResolver.setOrder(0);
        log.info("####   Internal view resolver 0 called...");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public StandardServletMultipartResolver multipartResolver(){
        log.info("####   Multipart resolver called...");
        return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
    }        
}
```

**Hibernate Configuration:**

```
package our.dcollect.configuration;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "our.dcollect")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"our.dcollect.repository"},  
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager")
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
//@PropertySource({ "/resources/hibernate.properties" })
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean(name="sessionFactory")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "our.dcollect" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(this.hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
     }

    @Bean(name="dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name="hibernateProperties")
    public Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        return properties;        
    }

    @Bean(name="transactionManager")
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("sessionFactory") SessionFactory s) {
       HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
       txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
       return txManager;
    }

    @Bean(name="jpaVendorAdapter")
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
            HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
            hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
            hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
            hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
            return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean(name="entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            lef.setDataSource(this.dataSource());
            lef.setJpaProperties(this.hibernateProperties());
            lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(this.jpaVendorAdapter());
            lef.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "our.dcollect.model"});
            return lef;
    }

}
```

**Hibernate Configuration for the Unit Tests:**

```
package our.dcollect.configuration;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

/***************************************************************************************
* The same as the real HibernateConfiguration but this works with H2 DB instead of MySQL.
* In addition, the properties are not read from a property file.
****************************************************************************************/
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "our.dcollect")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"our.dcollect.repository"},  
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactoryTest",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManagerTest")
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfigurationTest {


    @Bean(name = "sessionFactoryTest")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryTest() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSourceTest());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "our.dcollect" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernatePropertiesTest());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSourceTest")
    public DataSource dataSourceTest() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE");
        dataSource.setUsername("...");
        dataSource.setPassword("...");
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernatePropertiesTest() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManagerTest")
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManagerTest(@Qualifier("sessionFactoryTest") SessionFactory s) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
        return txManager;
    }


    @Bean(name = "jpaVendorAdapterTest")
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapterTest() {
            HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
            hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
            hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
            hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.H2);
            return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactoryTest")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryTest() {
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            lef.setDataSource(this.dataSourceTest());
            lef.setJpaProperties(this.hibernatePropertiesTest());
            lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(this.jpaVendorAdapterTest());
            lef.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "our.dcollect.model"});
            return lef;
    }

}
```

**The Unit Test class abbriviated for legibility:**

```
package our.dcollect.service;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import our.dcollect.configuration.AppConfiguration;
import our.dcollect.configuration.HibernateConfigurationTest;
import our.dcollect.model.OpenIC;
import our.dcollect.repository.OpenICRepository;

@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {AppConfiguration.class, HibernateConfigurationTest.class})
public class OpenPositionsServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private OpenICRepository OpenICDAO;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName  = "entityManagerFactoryTest")
    private EntityManager entityManager;



    @Test
    @Transactional(value="transactionManagerTest", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void testOIC() {
        System.out.println("getOpenPositionsNotRegisteredInPushBanch");

        OpenIC oic = new OpenIC();
        oic.setBaId("111");
        oic.setBezeichnung("abc");

        // clear the persistence context so we don't return the previously cached location object
        // this is a test only thing and normally doesn't need to be done in prod code
        entityManager.clear();

        OpenICDAO.saveAndFlush(oic);
        List<OpenIC> list = OpenICDAO.findAll();
        assertEquals(list.size(), 1);

        OpenIC oicReadBack = list.get(0);
        OpenICDAO.delete(oicReadBack.getOpenICId());

    }
[...]    
}
```

**Steps Towards the Solution:**

---

The posts from Funtik helped a lot. The following setps I carried out:

1. **@DependsOn("transactionManagerTest")** to tell Spring that the
   EntityManagerFactory needs to be loaded after the TransactionManager
   but it did not solve the problem.
2. **Introducing @Profile("test")** for HibernateConfigurationTest and    @Profile("!test") for HibernateConfiguration. On the test
   class I put    @ActiveProfiles("test"). This separated the beans;
   only one flavour    was loaded during the test: the ones in
   HibernateConfigurationTest.    This however did not solve the
   problem either.
3. Then **I completely removed one profile** in a separate branch to see    whether the two configuration for the DB cause the issue. I
   experienced the same problem with one DB configuration as before.
4. I added    **@TestExecutionListeners({TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,

   DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class}) to the unit test

   class** and **@Rollback(false) to the test method** to see whether
   anything    is saved in the MySQL database. I also changed
   "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" to "create", to preserve the DB after the
   test. It changed the situation as the message appeared in the log:
   "[...] **Began transaction (1) for test context**
   [DefaultTestContext@a15b73 [...]". So one transaction context has
   definitely been created and has had 1 transaction. The problem was
   however that the **entity was not persisted in the database** if I call 
   OpenICDAO.save(oic) in the test. In addition, calling
   OpenICDAO.saveAndFlush(oic) causes the nearly the exception below:

"[...] 4671 [main] WARN  org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager  - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@45c9b3] to process 'after' execution for test: method [public void our.dcollect.service.OpenPositionsServiceTest.testGetOpenPositionsNotRegisteredInPushBanch()], instance [our.dcollect.service.OpenPositionsServiceTest@dc7b7d], exception [org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: no transaction is in progress; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress]
org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only [...]"

**`Tests in error:`**

```
  testOIC(our.dcollect.service.OpenPositionsServiceTest): no transaction is in progress; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
  testOIC(our.dcollect.service.OpenPositionsServiceTest): Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only

Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0
```

However, I only have 2 methods not 3 from which testOIC is reported twice.

---

***Solution:***

The transactionManager must be a **PlatformTransactionManager** hosting a **JpaTransactionManager**. This solved the problem. Thank you for all the comments. I found the `@Profile` annotation very useful and the idea of listing the beans in the application context. After having the correct transactionManager, the annotation `DependsOn()` caused a circular reference, so I removed it; `@TestExecutionListeners` annotation is also not necessary in this case. I took a simple demo application that I changed to my configuration and tried to reproduce the original fault. After being able to reproduce it, I checked the differences between the good and bad state, it helped to find the difference. (The same also needs to be done for transactionManagerTest that expects a SessionFactoryTest object.)

```
//    @Bean(name="transactionManager")
//    @Autowired
//    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("sessionFactory") SessionFactory s) {
//       HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
//       txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
//       return txManager;
//    }

    @Bean(name="transactionManager")
    @Autowired
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("sessionFactory") SessionFactory s) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager( entityManagerFactory().getObject() );
    }
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you creating a separate session factory and an entity manager factory?  With hibernate, simply use the EMF and unwrap to the SF.

Comment: I can also try with that (SessionFactory sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);). I was not thinking about it just separated everything in two. As I can see it is Hibernate specific and works only with Hibernate. 

What is the main advantage of using this approach? Thank you for the idea.

Comment: You avoid having to create 2 different factories that must parse configuration, mappings, etc.  Hibernate is a JPA provider, so when you create an EntityManagerFactory, it is creating a SessionFactory in the background but simply exposes it as an EntityManagerFactory.  Unwrapping the EMF to a SF is just a short-cut to getting access to the Hibernate SessionFactory API.  Similarly, unwrapping an EM to a Session gives you access to the Hibernate Session API.

Comment: See the solution and thanks for the comments. I also tried unwrap () but LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean does not have an unwrap() method.

Comment: `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` is a factory bean in spring speak which when calling `getObject()` returns you an `EntityManagerFactory`.  The `EntityManagerFactory` is what has the `unwrap(Class<?>)` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the Solution to the original post at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. From what I experienced it seems that the entityManager bean is loaded before transactionManager bean, so the spring does not sense the presence of any transactions at all.

`@DependsOn` annotation fixed this issue for me. Try setting the explicit dependency on TransactionManager like this:

```
    @DependsOn("transactionManagerTest")
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactoryTest")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryTest() {
```

Comment: It did not changed the situation for me but liked the idea, so I added a vote. I have furthermore the exception, I have just added to the question.

Comment: could you autowire the application context into the unit test and output all of its beans? Just to verify that the transaction manager is actually present in the application context

Comment: I have added the list of the beans.

Comment: you should exclude your main datasource and related stuff from your test appcontext. You can use @Profile annotation to achieve that

Comment: Thanks, I have added the @Profile("test") for HibernateConfigurationTest and @Profile("!test") for HibernateConfiguration. On the test class I put @ActiveProfiles("test"). I checked the beans in the application context and only those were listed that belonged to the profile "test". However. it did not solve the problem. I am trying to go on, eliminate one profile and see whether it works if I have only one. I will get back and send a feedback.

Comment: In a new branch I completely removed the test configuration for hibernate, so I only have one bean of each type and I have the same exception: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: no transaction is in progress; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress I will test without transaction.

Comment: try adding the transactional test execution listener to your test class 
@TestExecutionListeners({TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class})

Comment: Thanks a lot it changed the situation. TransactionContext has been created. However, the test method does not save into the DB and seems to run twice. If I add the explicit call for flush(), then the same exception comes. The details I added to the original post below "Steps Towards the Solution".

Comment: Thanks for the comments, see the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this issue while trying to persist an entity during test.

And followed your solution in trying to resolve:

"The transactionManager must be a PlatformTransactionManager hosting a JpaTransactionManager"

Changed HibernateTransactionManager to JpaTransactionManager

```
    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory s) {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(s);
        return txManager;
    }
```

Was very amazed for your solution to work. If anyone could point me on documentation where it's described it would be great.
Thank you.